# Is there any way to use EFS (NFS4) to store docker container (writable) layer files without using volume or bind mount?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, nfs, amazon-efs

We want to have a large amount of storage to be available in our docker containers (launched on ECS with a custom EC2 AMI based on amazon-linux), each launched VM running our containers have a ~16TiB block storage volume (AWS EBS) attached to them. `/var/lib/docker` resides on this mounted AWS EBS volume. This EBS volume is not dynamic and most of the times it ends up being under-provisioned, which costs us a lot. AWS EFS (a manged NFS4 file system with sort of infinite storage) seems to be a right option for us, but I couldn't find any ideal way to make the docker storage-driver use this NFS (mounted to the host OS in each VM) to store the container (writable) layers. The configured storage-driver is devicemapper here.

Using volumes or bind mounts could be another ideal approach but as far as I understand, both of those options make some directory available inside your container which is either mounted to a host file system directory or a remote file system, and this same available directory could be shared across multiple containers. Performing read/writes on a specifc mounted dir inside our containers and ensuring haing a unique mount/volume dir inside NFS for each container is not feasible for us. We don't have much control over how we subit containers to ECS here as they are submitted to ECS via AWS Batch by a workflow tool named Nextflow.

I came across this blog while searching for a way to configure docker storage driver with NFS - https://whyistheinternetbroken.wordpress.com/2015/05/12/techusing-nfs-with-docker-where-does-it-fit-in/

The doc says all the container images are stored inside `/var/lib/docker` directory and if you mount this dir to NFS using -
`mount 10.228.225.142:/docker /var/lib/docker` command, then all the images are wriited inside /docker dir in the NFS. I tried it, and it does work. The devicemapper does not support NFS4, so I presume it's working because the devicemapper storage driver is just performing read/writes on '/var/lib/docker' and the rest is take care of by the NFS driver configured on the host OS.

But once I started testing this configuration, the VM stops responding mostly while running a container or pulling images. So, I wonder if there is an ideal way to accomplish what I want to achieve here?

Comment: It is not recommended approach for that size volume.

Comment: @PiyushPatil if not then why? How can volume and bind mount can support handling large volume read/write IO operations on a disk (or an NFS) flawlessly while the storage driver can't do it?